# Palettes going missing

Tags: interface

this is my first day with blender. Wow steep learning curve.

I keep losing my palettes. I'm down to two on screen and they haven't got little triangles in the corner so I can't drag to make more.

I don't seem to have collapse menus ticked. All I have on the Rhs is a a thing with transform which seems to be part of the 3d view window which is open. I can collapse and restore it with + but Previously I had palettes with a object tree and all sorts.

If I reload the app all is restored but as soon as I load the file I'm working on they go again. I suppose I could make a new doc and import but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Opening user preferences gave me a window with triangles and I was able to rebuild the UI in that but if I ever close the original window the app shuts down. Confused... Is there any way to make the new window 'primary' or to stop the UI being loaded with the file?

Thanks

Update: Hurray!!! I finally figured this out.

it happens if you go into the file open dialog and then instead of pressing OPEN or CANCEL, you use the window chooser to go back to 3D view. it leaves you with no drag handles.

The way to get out of it is to use the window chooser to go back into the 
file open dialog and OPEN or CANCEL.

Comment: I realise I can go back, but how would I stop it reverting on load?

Comment: Yes you are right, I missed the loadui box as I was opening from recent. Thanks